# Unable to access old (deleted) user's home folder and files and don't have permissions to read, write or delete them

Tags: permissions, users

I created a new user, granted admin rights to it and deleted my old user account.

Now I don't have access to deleted user's files and all that data.

I would like to replace the new user's home folder with that deleted old user's home folder which I now have to open by opening `/home/old_user/`

When I try to open the old user's files the following message is displaying:

> You  do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of this folder

I am not getting why I can't get access to my files as I am the only user of this laptop and I have granted administrator permissions to this account too.

Comment: because they belong to the old user not the new user

Comment: I myself was the old user jeez.I just switched my user account and deleted the old one that's all.  @ravery

Comment: you are now a new user, the computer doesn't know who is sitting at the keyboard, it only know which account is logged in, and the new account doesn't own the files

Comment: Okay.Now help me by giving a solution to this trouble.

Comment: what do you want to do? move them? just be able to open them ?? delete them? all of the above?

Comment: there is no option to **cut** the files.If i copy them then it will eat up my space and actually the data is in bulk so i will probably choose **all of the above** Btw i have the root password also.Wondering will ill it serve as any help?

Answer (score 2):

If you do have the root password and the current user is in sudoers group, you just have to chown recursively your /home/old_user/, something like :

```
sudo chown -R new_user:new_group /home/old_user/
```

In this case you should get the same permission as you had before. If you want to change them, use `chmod` with the appropriate code.

Comment: **new _group**?  Am i suppose to a create a new group or what? Btw i didn't understand this part of your answer **...and the current user is in sudoers group**.Can you be a little more specific?@Renon

Comment: When creating a new user, a new group of the same name is created with the new user in it, so if your new user is "pineapple", you just run `sudo chown -R pineapple:pineapple /home/old_user/` if you want this group to have permissions on this folder. 
If you can use `sudo`, you are in the sudoers group.

Comment: This answer is helpful, but OP also mentions that they want to replace the new home directory with the old home directory (which can be a bit tricky in terms of configuration, and might have some unintended effects).